# SQL Server Management Studio console window

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'd like to have a console window inside SSMS where I can run quickly a query to see what columns are in a specific table or test a query before writing it into a script and such things.
There are some addons for Visual Studio that provide cmd or powershell consoles where one can run commands. That's what I need in SSMS for SQL.

It'd be nice if that console would understand sql directly but I'd also be glad to have a powershell window embedded in SSMS if there's no other solution.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the SSMS windows into tab groups (Vertical or Horizontal)?  Not a powershell window, but will give you another tab in which to write queries.

Comment: Nope. But I already have a second script with test queries that I select and execute. Your recommendation would make that a little bit simpler but I'd really like to have a console window.

Comment: What difference do you want between "console window" and ssms query editor? I think it's just a far-fetched problem.

Comment: I don't want to select my query and hit F5 to run it. I want to just hit ENTER to run my query. I know how comfortable such a console can be because I already used one in Visual Studio and I'd like to have the same comfort in SSMS, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One trick that I like to use the default keyboard shortcut of Alt+F1 for sp_help. If you highlight a table name in a query window and hit that shortcut, it'll run sp_help with the table name as a parameter. This will give you all sorts of information on the table (columns, indexes, constraints).

Comment: ok, quite useful for that specific situation where I want to find out table specs. But sometimes I'd also like to get information from normal tables or to run a query to see if the script worked properly. I need a solution for that.

Comment: @wullxz why did you accept this answer if it doesn't solve your question?